# C: Child I/O with parent and keyboard

Tags: c, user-interface, pipe, tcl, io-redirection

Shortened Question:

I have a parent process that creates a child process as seen below:

```
int me2them[2], them2me[2];
pipe(me2them);pipe(them2me);
if (!fork()){
    close(0); dup2(me2them[0],0); close(me2them[0]); 
    close(1); dup2(them2me[1],1); close(them2me[1]);
    char * cmds[] = {"wish", "myProg.tcl",NULL};
    execvp(cmds[0], cmds); 
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to exec 1\n");
    exit(-1);
}
close(0); dup2(them2me[0],0); close(them2me[0]); 
close(1); dup2(me2them[1],1); close(me2them[1]);
```

But, I need the child process to be able to recieve input from the user.  With this method, the stdin for the child is changed from the keyboard to the stdout of the parent.  How can I maintain communication with both the keyboard and the parent?

Also, the parent is the client of a server, and thus multiple parents can be running on the same or different machines, making a shared file between parent and child difficult because the child of any parent would be able to access any other parent's file.

NOTE: I'd prefer to keep the parent's stdout being mapped to the child's input because I did not write the c code and I want to re-route its printf statements to the child.

Original Version:

I am using tcl to make a GUI for a c code.  The tcl is a child process of the c code and I use I/O redirection to make the stdout of the c to be the stdin of the tcl and the stdout of the tcl to be the stdin of the c.  However,  there is a part where the c requests the user's name and it sends the request via stdout to the stdin of the tcl code, no problems, then the tcl requests the name.  The tcl name request presents two problems:

1) tcl is in effect sending the request to the c code, causing the c code to mistake the request as being the actual name (solved by sending the request to stderr instead of stdout)

2) When tcl attempts to get the user input for the name, it will be checking stdin, which is mapped to receive from the c code not the keyboard, and will not be able to read the response from the user.

Is there a way to specify to get the response from the keyboard? Or should I map the stdout of the c code to a different fd for the tcl? And if so, how do I specify to get from the keyboard/new fd.

Here is how I make the tcl a child process of the c code:

```
int me2them[2], them2me[2];
pipe(me2them);pipe(them2me);
if (!fork()){
    close(0); dup2(me2them[0],0); close(me2them[0]); 
    close(1); dup2(them2me[1],1); close(them2me[1]);
    char * cmds[] = {"wish", "myProg.tcl",NULL};
    execvp(cmds[0], cmds); 
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to exec 1\n");
    exit(-1);
}
close(0); dup2(them2me[0],0); close(them2me[0]); 
close(1); dup2(me2them[1],1); close(me2them[1]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if the child would have a conventional command-line interface, e.g.,line-buffered.  I suggest these design changes:

- modify the two-way pipe to the child to something other than its standard input and output (you can read/write on other streams)
- it might be simplest to make that change within the child
- you can use `dup2`, etc., within the child to modify the pipe.  That leaves the question of how to get a usable keyboard interface for the child.
- you can solve *that* problem by opening `/dev/tty` directly, and (again with `dup2` and friends) making the file opened on `/dev/tty` into the child's standard input and output.

As an example, the [dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html) program has a feature for reading data via a pipe (at the shell level, that is its standard input), and in initialization, changing that into a different stream and opening `/dev/tty` for a "real" standard input.  Your problem is a little more complicated (with both input and output pipes), but reading the `dialog` source may be helpful.  For reference, that is the `init_dialog` function in `util.c` (source [here](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html#download)).

Comment: The child process is a tcl program, do you know how to do the equivalent of `dup2` in tcl?

Comment: @CSjunkie: No need to dup stdin and stdout in tcl. Leave them as is and just open `/dev/tty` directly to read from the keyboard as if it was a file.